# "The parameter is incorrect" error when trying to get a registry key using Windows API via windows crate

Tags: windows, rust, windows-rs

I am trying to get a registry key using Windows API via the `windows` crate. But I am getting this error:

```
Error: Error { code: HRESULT(0x80070057), message: "The parameter is incorrect." }
```

Here is my code:

```rs
pub fn get_registry_key<'a>(hkey: HKEY, subkey: &'a str, key: &'a str, flags: REG_ROUTINE_FLAGS) -> Result<*mut c_void, windows::core::Error> {
    unsafe {
        let mut data: *mut c_void;
        let mut data_length: u32 = 0;
        // Stores the subkey and key
        let subkey_hstring = HSTRING::from(subkey);
        let key_hstring = HSTRING::from(key);

        // Get the data length to allocate memory
        RegGetValueW(hkey, PCWSTR(subkey_hstring.as_ptr()), PCWSTR(key_hstring.as_ptr()), flags, None, None, Some(&mut data_length))?;
        println!("Length: {}", data_length);
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align(data_length as usize, 1).unwrap();
        data = std::alloc::alloc(layout) as *mut c_void;

        RegGetValueW(hkey, PCWSTR(subkey_hstring.as_ptr()), PCWSTR(key_hstring.as_ptr()), flags, None, Some(data), None)?;
        Ok(data)
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew), I should be doing it correctly. I am able to get the data length and allocate memory to it but cannot get the data itself. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation

> The pcbData parameter can be NULL only if pvData is NULL.

But you set `pcbData` to `None` in your second call while `pvData` is `Some(data)`.
You have to pass `Some(&mut data_length)` again:

```rust
pub fn get_registry_key<'a>(hkey: HKEY, subkey: &'a str, key: &'a str, flags: REG_ROUTINE_FLAGS) -> Result<*mut c_void, windows::core::Error> {
    unsafe {
        let mut data: *mut c_void;
        let mut data_length: u32 = 0;
        // Stores the subkey and key
        let subkey_hstring = HSTRING::from(subkey);
        let key_hstring = HSTRING::from(key);

        // Get the data length to allocate memory
        RegGetValueW(hkey, PCWSTR(subkey_hstring.as_ptr()), PCWSTR(key_hstring.as_ptr()), flags, None, None, Some(&mut data_length))?;
        println!("Length: {}", data_length);
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align(data_length as usize, 1).unwrap();
        data = std::alloc::alloc(layout) as *mut c_void;

        RegGetValueW(hkey, PCWSTR(subkey_hstring.as_ptr()), PCWSTR(key_hstring.as_ptr()), flags, None, Some(data), Some(&mut data_length))?;
        Ok(data)
    }
}
```